# Trigonometry Question

Tags: trigonometry

In trigonometry to measure the height or distance of objects we consider the distance between the observer and object to be straight. But the surface of the earth is curved. Assuming the line to be straight, doesn't it cause any error, or are the distances too small to cause significant error?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by *significant error*, but isn't this more of a physics question than a mathematics question?

Comment: "Locally" the Earth, or at least the surface of the ocean, is flat. For modest distances, it makes no practical difference. What sorts of distances do you have in mind? $100$ metres? $1$ km? $10$ km? $100$?

Comment: You are more likely to have error caused by localized variation in topology unless you are on the ocean.  There will always, however, be some error because of this assumption. This is a useful example for classes but I generally use trig for more complex systems then finding the height of a building or other tall object.

Comment: For finding inaccessible objects like mountains we use trigonometry. Doesn't it result in errenous answer? How is it rectified?

Comment: @RanjanYajurvedi: I can't answer but suggest that you may look up in textbooks on surveying and cartography.